# Accessing kerberos secured webhdfs from browser

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, webhdfs

I'm unable to access WebHDFS from browser(IE8) due to Kerberos security. Can anyone please help me with this?

I used “curl” works fine

curl -i  --negotiate -u:qjdht93 "http://:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/qjdht93/?op=LISTSTATUS"

Below is the error in browser for “http://:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/qjdht93/?op=LISTSTATUS”

[image]

I found below link which explains steps to access URL which is protected by Kerberos, Might be useful

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_sg_browser_access_kerberos_protected_url.html

Comment: Did you add KDC using "ksetup" command in your machine?

Comment: You have to map your cluster hostname for http. I mean you have to map your http/hostname principal to all hostname in your cluster.